# How to hide current content by clicking outside its area, and when I show another content in IE11?

Tags: javascript

Clicking on the button shows and hides the corresponding content.

```js
    function funC(id) {
       var el = document.getElementById(id);
        if(el.style.display == 'inline-block')
           el.style.display = '';
       else
           el.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
```

```css
button {margin:2px; outline:0; font-size:12px;}
span   {padding:2px; border:1px solid silver; 
        font-size:12px;}
.cb    {display:none;}
```

```html
<button onclick="funC('cnt1');">b1</button><span id="cnt1" class="cb">content b1...</span>
<br />
<button onclick="funC('cnt2');">b2</button><span id="cnt2" class="cb">content b2...</span>
<br />
<button onclick="funC('cnt3');">b3</button><span id="cnt3" class="cb">content b3...</span>
```

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Ar7en/vcuh3q32/)
1. But, how to hide content when clicking outside its area, 
and as with showing the next content, hide the previous one?
2.  Is it possible to do the same without using id?
Only pure javascript. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be a perfect solution but here is a proposition :

```js
function hideAllContent() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".cb");
  for(var i =0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
      var element = elements[i];
      element.visible = false;
      element.style.display='none';
  }    
}

function funC(id, event) {
    // We need to stop the event to avoid bubling until the body
    event.stopPropagation();

    // let's hide others before displaying the new one
    hideAllContent();

    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if(el.visible) {
        el.visible = false;
        el.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        el.visible = true;
        el.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
}

document.body.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('cb')) {
        hideAllContent();
    }
}
```

```css
button {margin:2px; outline:0; font-size:12px;}
span   {padding:2px; border:1px solid silver; 
        font-size:12px;}
.cb    {display:none;}
```

```html
<button onclick="funC('cnt1', event);">b1</button><span id="cnt1" class="cb">content b1...</span>
<br />
<button onclick="funC('cnt2', event);">b2</button><span id="cnt2" class="cb">content b2...</span>
<br />
<button onclick="funC('cnt3', event);">b3</button><span id="cnt3" class="cb">content b3...</span>
```

About avoiding ids, you could use the target property on click event and find the sibling node or something like that or use a querySelector. But ids are safe and fine i would say.

Comment: Thank you, Sam. But does not work in the IE 11.0 browser.

Comment: Thank you, Sam. Works in IE11.0, but why is the content not hidden by the back click on the button, as it was originally?

Comment: Hey, as it's pure JavaScript actions, i don't see any reason for the backup history to work here. However i guess it would still be possible to manipulate it through the history api (maybe you can have a look to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). Anyway, hope you find what you need :)

Answer (score 1):

- No inline on-clicks attached.
- No IDs use.
- Used backward-compatible syntax for IE 11.

```js
// JavaScript

// get all button and span tags
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
var otherSpans = document.querySelectorAll('span');

// Detect all clicks on the document
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 const spanElems = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    const spanElemsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(spanElems);

    let matches = event.target.matches ? event.target.matches('button') : event.target.msMatchesSelector('button');

    // If user clicks inside the element, do nothing
    if (matches) {
      return;
    } else {
      // If user clicks outside the element, hide it!
      spanElemsArray.forEach( function (spanElem) {
       spanElem.classList.remove("open");
      });
    }
});

// convert buttons and spans variable objects to arrays
const btnsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(btns);
const otherSpansArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(otherSpans);

// loop through every button and assign a click to each one
btnsArray.forEach( function (btn) {
 btn.addEventListener('click', spanFunc)
});

// Pass the button clicked as a reference
function spanFunc(){
 openSpan(this);
}

// toggle the display class on the span next to the button using nextElementSibling method
function openSpan(e) {
    e.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("open");
     
        // hide every other spans
        function otherSpanFunc() {
           otherSpansArray.forEach( function (otherSpan) {
             if (otherSpan !== e.nextElementSibling) {
                   otherSpan.classList.remove('open');
                }
            });
        }
     otherSpanFunc();
     
}
```

```css
/* css */

button {margin:2px; outline:0; font-size:12px;}
span   {padding:2px; border:1px solid silver; 
        font-size:12px;}
.cb    {display:none;}
.open {display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<button>b1</button><span class="cb">content b1...</span>
<br />
<button>b2</button><span class="cb">content b2...</span>
<br />
<button>b3</button><span class="cb">content b3...</span>
```

---

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ypofz4d5/55/

Comment: Thank you, AndrewL. Good, but, the content does not hide when clicking outside the area. Also, the code does not work in the IE 11.0 browser.

Comment: Code edited. Any clicks outside buttons will close spans and syntax is IE11 compatible now.

Comment: And Microsoft has stop providing support for Internet Explorer except for basic security updates and is now focusing on Microsoft Edge so it's highly recommendable to move on to standard browsers now Arsen.

Comment: Thank you, AndrewL. But in IE 11 content is not hidden by clicking outside the area.

Comment: It works in IE 11, except for hiding the content, by clicking outside the area.

Comment: msMatchesSelector should make the above work in ie11 too now. Check it out.

Comment: Damn. That's disappointing. Hope someone else here can find out what is going wrong in the above code. Cheers

Comment: Hi @AndrewL, `spanElems` is not a real array, it's a nodeList. I don't think you can use `forEach` on that in ie11

Comment: @Sam Oh yeah. I forgot to change it to an array before looping it. Let me try changing that to an array and see if it fixes it. Thanks for pointing that out man.

Comment: Thanks to Sam's help, the updated code should be working fine now in IE 11.

Comment: Glad we could help Arsen. Do upvote our answers and tick the solution to help other users with the same issue in the long run :) Cheers!